# How to include an animated GIF image in a Stack Overflow answer

Tags: support, images

I have seen an animated GIF image in a Stack Overflow answer. This is helpful as it visually shows the steps to be taken to perform an solution. How do I attach an animated GIF image to my answer?

I believe this question is relevant to programming since there is no icon on the answer screen that can include a GIF image. It has a link or an image icon. If I try to embed an image it only accepts standard image file formats such as JPEG, PNG, but not GIF. Also there isn't any keyboard shortcut.

This would help me and others improve their answers by showing visually how to accomplish tasks rather than simply by words.

Comment: Or even better: don't.

Comment: While an animation can, sometimes, be quite helpful when showing what to do in a GUI, a text version of what steps to perform is *highly* preferred, at least in addition to an animation/screen recording. Please keep in mind that a substantial number of people *can't* see any image or animation which you might include, so an image/animation definitely shouldn't be the only thing showing/describing the actions or information which your answer, or question, is trying to convey.

Comment: And a substantial number of people who *can* see images and animations, are hugely annoyed by unwanted, unprompted, unending animations.

Comment: @ThomA [brilliantly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416797/673991) validates the question. Banish the misuse, not the feature.

Answer (score 9):

Just like you would with any other image; the process is no different. Click the image button (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>), and the put the URL, and then *"Browse, drag & drop, or paste an image or link"*.

[image: Cursor clicks the Image button in the Answer Menu Bar. Cursor moves off screen. Windows Explorer Appears. Cursor Drags and Drops Image into the Answer Pane. Cursor clicks "Add Picture" button.]

If you look at the Markdown for this answer, as well, you'll note I have used descriptive text for the alternative text of the image. As noted in the comments, the image should not *be* the answer, it should complement it.

Comment: The problem with this is when I browse image it does not show files with extenstion gif.

Comment: @TheWizEd .gif is included in the list of allowed file extensions by the site/server, so if you are not finding the file then it is either not actually saved as a .gif extension, or in a different place on your computer.

Comment: That's a problem with your file then, @TheWizEd ; that has nothing to do with Stack Overflow. Perhaps, for example, you're creating a mp4, or mov file and expecting to be able to upload that and have it (implicitly) converted to a gif. You need to explicitly create a gif.

Comment: I disagree, I see the file in MS Explorer in a known directory but it does not show up in stackoverflow Browse.

Comment: Have you tried drag and dropping, like I demonstrate, @TheWizEd ? Though I [can see gif files just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c24rJ.png).

Comment: @TheWizEd Not sure what to tell you. When I click "browse", the explorer prompt that opens [explicitly allows `*.gif` files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3DMl.png). You should still be able to drag and drop the file on the editor prompt without clicking browse though, which should work regardless.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  I will have to play around with my system to see why its different.

Comment: @TheWizEd Can you take a screenshot of the explorer window with file extensions shown and with the file upload dialog window visible as well?